# How does/ is srand calcuted?

Tags: c++

My question is straightforward. I know abour srand and rand, I know how to seed my random generator and so on. I am specifically interested in the mathematics behind srand. How does the computer use let's say 3333 as a seed and calculates a "random" number?

Comment: There are quite a few examples of simple pseudo-random number generators on the Internet, if you just search a little. But to be able to understand and write a *good* generator takes a lot of studying and experience, including plenty of math and statistics.

Comment: i dont understand the question, when you call `srand` then you pass the seed as parameter. Do you want to know how the first random number is generated from that seed?

Comment: Let's take the example with srand(time). Here the first number ALWAYS follows the UNIX time which makes sense. The other numbers are generated by using the previous number as a seed. But question is just how does srand take a seed and calculates the next "random" number? Computers never do "random" things but can use matemathics to perfom what would seem like "randomness".

Comment: Ps. Sorry about my formalia on Stack, I am completly new here, and need to study a bit to find out how to highlight things and so on((:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The c standard library's and therefore the c++ standard library's [`std::rand`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) implementation is up to the library implementation. It is not mandated by the standard. The following function

[image: int getRandomNumber() { return 4; }]

<sub>(source: https://xkcd.com/221/)</sub>

would be a perfectly valid implementation for it.

That is the reason why ***it should under no circumstances be used any more***. Instead defer to the well-defined, implementation independent and portable [mersenne twister](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine).

Comment: you beat me by 1 second to find the pic :P

Comment: @idclev463035818 Well if it's any consolation, that usually happens to me :)

Comment: Yes but such an implementation would be a terrible mess. Indeed random but nothing is more deterministic than a constant value. So I'm not sure anyone would call such an implementation "valid" in practice (even if it does not violate the standard).

Comment: [Another related comic](https://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25)

Comment: @Fareanor Of course not. But the point is that given that the standard *allows* this, means that pretty much any implementation (deterministic depending on seed) would conform. Which makes `rand` pretty much useless for any practical application.

Comment: @Fareanor I think part of the joke is that unless you know how it is implemented you cannot tell the difference between this and a real prng

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Perhaps, but I wouldn't be thrilled to be associated with Scott Adams or his work in any way.

Comment: @bitmask I fully agree with that, I posted my comment before your edit _"That is the reason..."_ :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the library implementation but in general it would be enough to calculate a well mixed hash of the argument.